# Selenium - Refresh page that takes too long to load

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, pyautogui

I have a forloop that will open up a webpage from a list, screenshot the page and then move onto the next webpage on the list.

I run into a problem where the browser has trouble loading a page, but a simple manual refresh does the trick and gets the script running once again. How do i incorporate a refresh timer so that if loading the page takes longer than 5 seconds, the page refreshes?

I'm not sure how to incorporate the time library or the driver.refresh() command.

Ill leave my code below.

```
for links in link:
    driver.get(links)
    pyautogui.screenshot('/Users/user/Desktop/autoscreen/Screenshots/hehh/'+ links + '.png').
```

Comment: Where's your code that even attempts the timeout and page refresh?

Answer (score 1):

In general, you need to tell the driver how long to wait before timing out, and then trap the timeout exception. In the timeout exception, call driver.refresh(). You may need to make this a little more robust, but this is the gist.

```
# Wait up to 30 seconds for page to load
driver.implicitly_wait(30)

for link in links:
    try:
         driver.get(link)
         pyautogui.screenshot('/Users/user/Desktop/autoscreen/Screenshots/hehh/'+ links + '.png')
     except TimeoutException:
         driver.refresh()
```

Comment: interesting thanks! do you think an explicit wait would be better in this case?

Comment: I usually favor explicit waits if I can identify a specific target element.